# mathematical equations in ASP classic

Tags: math, asp-classic

I'm programming in ASP classic and I need to solve mathematical operations, for example, I have a string

a = "5 +3"

How I can get the result from the string? 
If there is no way to know any web service to sorting the problem.

thank you very much

Comment: mhh just remove the Quotation marks?

Comment: @ulluoink They asked *"How I can get the result from the string?"*, so removing the quotation marks isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example:

```
<%
    'Condition
    a = "5+3"

    'Split
    b = split(a,"+")

    'For each number find, sum
    for each item in b
        'Convert the string to Int using CInt()
        sum = sum + Cint(item)
    next

    response.write sum
%>
```

Or Just

```
<%
    a = "5+3"
    response.write EVal(a)
%>
```

For another math operators, you can use this logic as well.

Comment: The Eval function evaluates an expression, like a function, and returns the result. The ´for´ loop is only a didactic way to demonstrate what should happen. Only Eval, does not show it. I've learn that in the university, even exist some functions to save our live, try to demonstrate what is happening to a better understanding.

Comment: Agreed, but `"5+3"` is a string expression so what's your point?

Answer (score -1):

```
execute(a = 5 +3)
response.write(a)
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does your code solve the given problem?

Comment: Sorry ! the right code is :
execute("a = 5 +3")
response.write(a)

You can also try this :
MyString = "a = 5 +3"
execute(MyString)
response.write(a)